# How to solve "Error while loading rule 'react/display-name': `[[GeneratorState]]` is not present on `O`" error in eslint

Tags: npm, next.js, eslint, hadoop-yarn, bun

In my case I am using `eslint` on `nextjs` with `eslint-config-next`. I use `bun` as a package manager but I found instances of this issues on `npm` and `yarn` as well.

I didn't add any new package but after running `bun update` or `yarn update` the issues started appearing. Linting fails with the error:

```
Error while loading rule 'react/display-name': `[[GeneratorState]]` is not present on `O`
Occurred while linting ...
```

Answer (score 9):

After some research, I found out similar issues reported on the `eslint-plugin-react` repo and on its dependencies.
This issue is related with errors in dependency resolution, when multiple incompatible versions of the same package are installed by the package manager. A similar issue was reported [here](https://github.com/es-shims/iterator-helpers/issues/4#issuecomment-1783852932). The solution is to remove duplicate dependencies:

- If you are using `npm`, the solution is to run `npm dedupe`
- If you are using `yarn`, you can do the same by installing [yarn-deduplicate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-deduplicate)
- If you are using `pnpm`, the solution is to run `pnpm dedupe`
- If you are using `bun` then you are in no luck because there is currently no dedupe command. In that case you should:

  - Generate yarn.lock from your bun.lock with `bun install --yarn` so you can inspect the dependencies
  - Use [yarn-deduplicate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-deduplicate) to fix your `yarn.lock` file
  - Wait for this issue to be solved so you can regenarate your `bun.lockb` from the fixed `yarn.lock`

What `npm dedupe` does, is simplifying dependencies by aggregating duplicated dependencies so they are shared across packages.

Answer (score 4):

For those using yarn I found that [yarn-deduplicate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-deduplicate) resolved:
`[[GeneratorState]] is not present on O`
error for eslint-config-next

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked is:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock
yarn install
```